# How to prevent a gesture inside a UITableViewCell from interfering with the UITableView's scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I feel like this question has been asked numerous times before, but I've been hunting for days now and can't find an effective solution. In Swift 4, I have a UITableView in which each UITableViewCell has touchable UIView inside it. This UIView has a UILongPressGestureRecognizer attached to it that affects its depressed state and navigates to another screen when pressed. All of the rows are relatively close together, and unfortunately, in order to start a pan gesture to scroll the UITableView, you have to press on a list item, which triggers its gesture recognizer and immediately navigates away from the page.

Originally, you couldn't press on a UITableViewCell to trigger a scroll, so I set the gesture delegate in my UIView and added this function:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Thus leading to the issue I'm currently having. Here is the custom UIView class I am using inside the UITableViewCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ItemViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func tapped()
}

class ItemView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: ItemViewDelegate?
    var parent: UIViewController?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initializeGestureRecognition()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initializeGestureRecognition()
    }

    lazy var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = {
        let cubicParameters = UICubicTimingParameters(controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5))
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.1, timingParameters: cubicParameters)

        animator.isInterruptible = true

        return animator
    }()

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if (type(of: otherGestureRecognizer) == UIPanGestureRecognizer.self) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    private func initializeGestureRecognition() {
        let tapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(from:)))

        tapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    private func tapped() {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.tapped()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.roundCorners(radius: 4)
        self.addShadow(opacity: 0.06, radius: 4)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(from recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            if animator.isRunning {
                animator.stopAnimation(true)
            }

            animator.addAnimations {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.98, y: 0.98)
            }

            animator.startAnimation()
        case .ended:
            if animator.isRunning {
                animator.stopAnimation(true)
            }

            animator.addAnimations {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }

            animator.startAnimation()

            self.tapped()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I thought for sure the `shouldRequireFailureOf` override would work, as that's what Apple's docs seemed to suggest, but I've tried just about everything now and am pulling my hair out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define this var inside the VC that holds the tableView

```
var isScrolling = false
```

//

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate
```

//

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    isScrolling = true

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    isScrolling = false

}
```

//

and inside cell read this value

```
@objc func handleTap(from recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   if parentVc.isScrolling {  return  }

    .....
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work... unfortunately, by the time the user lifts their finger from the view, isScrolling has been set back to false and the tap event is processed anyway.